# Firefox Addon: how to remove preferences when addon is being uninstalled?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have the following piece of code in my Firefox addon:

```
var firstrun = Services.prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun");

if (firstrun) {
  // alert("first run");
  Services.prefs.setBoolPref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun", false);
  installButton("nav-bar", "custom-button-1");
} else {
  // alert("not first run");
}
```

In addon_dir/defaults/preferences/pref.js, I have the following string:

```
pref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun", true);
```

When addon runs for the first time, the code above understands it and installs a button on the toolbar. Also, it adds the following string to profile_dir/prefs.js:

```
user_pref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun", false);
```

It works fine. The only thing that bothers is this string in profile_dir/prefs.js is not cleared when I uninstall the addon. So, if I install this addon for the second time, the firstrun value is false, and the button is not added to the toolbar.

**Question: is it possible to remove addon preferences (in my case, user_pref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun", false);) when addon is uninstalled?**

A note: I have read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/Appendix_B%3a_Install_and_Uninstall_Scripts), but still have no idea what event to wait for. Any working example? I believe it is a common operation for addon creators and am very surprised there are no articles explaining these matters in detail.

Comment: Also there is the edge case of [the user who cancels a pending uninstall](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples#Listening_for_addon_uninstall)

Comment: If you solved your problem, you should add the way you solved it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Paa, thanks, I have read this. In my case, it's not critical, since it's no big deal if they changed their minds. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddonManager.addAddonListener({
    onUninstalling: function(addon){
        // alert("uninstalling!");   
        Services.prefs.setBoolPref("extensions.CustomButton.firstrun", true);
    }
  });
```

Comment: So in which script do you have to add this? I have the same problem here: [How do I set preferences in the user branch and unset them on uninstall?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23985279)

Comment: If you want to use this way you have to add it globally in bootstrap.js. Because if addon is disabled, then browser restarted, then user clicks uninstall, then all globals in bootstrap initialize. So that will make this listener get added.

Answer (score 2):

In [my Add-On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985279/set-preferences-in-the-user-branch-and-unset-them-on-uninstall), where I set this on install:

```
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
var pref = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
pref.setIntPref("network.http.response.timeout", 3600*24);
```

I solved it like this, that in my `main.js` I added this code at the end:

```
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    //called when add-on is 
    //    uninstalled
    //    disabled
    //    shutdown
    //    upgraded
    //    downgraded
    pref.clearUserPref("network.http.response.timeout");
};
```

That worked on disabling and uninstalling the addon.

Note: this is still not perfect, see comments. I will have to work on this ...

Comment: You actually need to declare `clearUserPref`, rubo77. For those of you looking to use this method, check out my answer to @rubo77's original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23985279/set-preferences-in-the-user-branch-and-unset-them-on-uninstall

Comment: I dont have to declare the function `clearUserPref` But I added the declaration of `pref`

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken: i guess it works like this but it is not a good solution. I will try to declare it in a few days...

Answer (score 2):

For bootstrap addons there is an `uninstall()` procedure, but for it to trigger you must use `install()` procedure, simply passing it two arguments and leaving the function blank will work.

Here is what I use in my add-ons:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/e0d3c21ab38822fbfd17

```
function uninstall(aData, aReason) {
    console.info('UNINSTALLING ZOOMR reason = ', aReason);
    if (aReason == ADDON_UNINSTALL) { //have to put this here because uninstall fires on upgrade/downgrade too
        //this is real uninstall
        var prefPrefix = 'extensions.my-addon@jetpack.';
        console.log('deleting branch of: ' + prefPrefix);
        Services.prefs.deleteBranch(prefPrefix);
    }
}
```