# Set preferences in the user branch and unset them on uninstall

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I created a firefox add-on with the following [`lib/main.js`](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/21d03191015fd7e618aa):

```
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");
var pref = Cc["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPrefBranch);
pref.setIntPref("network.http.response.timeout", 3600*24);
```

It wasn't accepted with the following reason:

> Add-ons which change critical settings must revert the changes when disabled or uninstalled. You should also make the changes in the default, rather than the user, branch.
>
> You need to call `getDefaultBranch("")` on the preferences service, and call the preference methods on the returned object rather than on the preference service directly.

To revert a preference back to the default, set by `setIntPref()`, I found out that I have to do [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPrefBranch#clearUserPref%28%29) on uninstall:

```
pref.clearUserPref("network.http.response.timeout")
```

This command works fine If I call it in another test-addon. I only have to find out [How to implement a command, so it is executed when the firefox-addon is uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012750/how-to-implement-a-command-so-it-is-executed-when-the-firefox-addon-is-uninstall)

So how do I have to understand these comments? How do I set the preferences in a "user branch"?

Comment: I think I understand the reason that this isn't getting unset. Because you're setting it as a default value, it's not a user pref. That is, if you look in about:config, you're probably going to see that the pref is of type 'default', which means that `clearUserPref` will only clear it back to the default value, not remove it. I don't know how to solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved **the second part** (uninstall)  like this, that in my `main.js` I added this code at the end:

```
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    //called when add-on is 
    //    uninstalled
    //    disabled
    //    shutdown
    //    upgraded
    //    downgraded
    pref.clearUserPref("network.http.response.timeout");
};
```

That worked on disabling and uninstalling the add-on.

Comment: A very very useful answer, ploease accept it. Is there an equivalent for startup? Like to get reason on startup of th eaddon for like enabled/upgraded/downgraded/installed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it just now:

```
function clearPrefBranch(aPrefBranchName) {                                     
  var defaultBranch = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(null);                    
  defaultBranch.deleteBranch(aPrefBranchName);                                  
}
```

Then, just call `clearPrefBranch` with an argument of `extensions.mypluginname` (assuming you used the naming convention, and you should be able to delete all of your extension's installed preferences.

**EDIT**:

The code I used inside of my main.js file:

```
const {Cc,Ci,Cm,Cr,Cu} = require("chrome");                                     
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");  

exports.onUnload = function(aOptions, aCallbacks) {                             
  MyPlugin.shutdown();                                                           
};

function clearPrefBranch(aPrefBranchName) {                                     
  var defaultBranch = Services.prefs.getDefaultBranch(null);                    
  defaultBranch.deleteBranch(aPrefBranchName);                                  
}

var MyPlugin = {
  shutdown: function() {                                                      
    prefLoader.clearPrefBranch('extensions.oopstab');                         

  }
};
```

Comment: I guess in your case, it would be: `clearPrefBranch('network.http.response');`

Comment: You know, I suppose if you wanted to delete just that one pref, you could do: `clearPrefBranch('network.http.response.timeout')`, since I doubt `nsIPrefBranch` cares about whether the given "branch" of the pref tree is actually a leaf...

Comment: How did you do it? it doesn't work at my addon. I tried to add your lines to main.js instead of my `pref.setIntPref("network.http.response.timeout", 3600*24);` and then I used `cfx xpi` to create a new version that just should reset the value for `network.http.response.timeout` to default. but it didn't

Comment: And why not just use `pref.clearUserPref("network.http.response.timeout");` ?

Comment: rubo77, given that you utilized my answer, would you mind accepting it?

Comment: let's continue in chat: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/736/discussion-about-firefox-addons

Comment: I just solved the second part for now. I will try in a few days with your code...