# How to implement a command, so it is executed when the firefox-addon is uninstalled?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I created a Firefox add-on with the Add-on SDK.

My script adds something to firefox, which doesn't matter here. How are the steps to implement a function that is called on uninstall and on disabling?

I read [this Code Samples article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples#Listening_for_addon_uninstall), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager), [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/Code_Samples#Uninstall_an_addon) and [this manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#addAddonListener%28%29) and [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532962/firefox-addon-how-to-remove-preferences-when-addon-is-being-uninstalled?lq=1), but didn't manage it, it doesn't seem to work or I am lacking of information where to add this and what else I have to program around it.

Also the manual seems to be outdated, cause When I add code from there and compile it with:

```
cfx xpi
```

I get warnings, that I should use `const {Cu} = require("chrome");` instead of the `Components` Object - Which i did then and compiled without error, but still, I couldnt get a command to be executed on uninstall yet.

Do I need to write it all in the main.js file? Or do I need an extra unistall file that is called?

Can you give a running example on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main.js`, use [`exports.onUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload#exports.onUnload%28%29).

So, in `main.js`;

```
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
    //called when add-on is 
    //    uninstalled
    //    disabled
    //    shutdown
    //    upgraded
    //    downgraded
};
```

Comment: In this code you would react if 'reason' is 'uninstall'.

Comment: 'uninstall' is not reliable due to [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=620541). so you should react to 'disabled'

Comment: I didn't react to reason at all and it seemed to work: `exports.onUnload = function(reason) { /* do my uninstall stuff */ }`

Comment: this means you're doing your uninstall stuff on every shutdown/upgrade which might not be what you want